# Pushwoosh, how do I send 'open app' push notifications with custom data via the API?

Tags: react-native, pushwoosh

I having trouble send a Pushwoosh notification using the API that matches what I can do in the web interface.

In the web interface, I navigate to the Action tab and select 'Open App' and enter custom json in the data field. This sends a notification that when clicked, triggers an even in my app and passes in custom data.

I have tried to recreate this using the [createmessage API](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/createmessage) by passing in custom data. Using the [Ruby client API](https://github.com/pedroandrade/pushwoosh) I run
`Pushwoosh.notify_devices("test", device_ids, { data: { foo: 1 } })`. This triggers a push but when the user taps on the push notification it opens the app but does not pass any data or call any of the callbacks in my app when the app opens.

Am I using the wrong API or missing parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use "**data**" parameter in *createMessage*?

It will be passed as "**u**" parameter in the push payload.

> "data": {"key":"value"},       *// JSON string or JSON object, will be passed as "u" parameter in the payload (converted to JSON string)*

If you want to modify the payload at any level you can use "**ios_root_params**"/"**android_root_params**" which is a JSON object and will be merged at the **root** level of the push payload.

Comment: I clarified the question with a code example. As I mentioned, I am using the "data" parameter in `createMessage`. Despite this, no data is passed and no callback is fired when the user taps the push notification.

Comment: Is there any possibility to see what exactly is in the createMessage request body that goes from the device? Any chance to dump the request body to the console? That would REALLY help.